# ActiveRecord joins throwing Column in where clause is ambiguous error - Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord

I'm working on a Rails 5.1 project which required the indexing and searching of `Project` records by values of the record's fields, and by the existence of a connected `Category` record (`Project` has and belongs to many `Category`).

I have a `SearchController` with a `search` action, which contains a form collecting search parameters. In the form, I have an input for a name parameter and a select for the category. The search runs successfully unless the search returns 0 results, all works ok when there are results to return. In cases where there should be no results, ActiveRecord throws the error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Column 'name' in where clause is ambiguous: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `projects` INNER JOIN `categories_projects` ON `categories_projects`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id` INNER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `categories_projects`.`category_id` WHERE (name LIKE '%something%') AND `categories`.`id` = 1
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

**Project Model**

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

**Category Model**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end
```

**SearchController**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def search
    projects = Project.all
    projects = projects.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:name]}%") if params[:name].present?
    projects = projects.joins(:categories).where(categories: { id: params[:category_id] }) if params[:category_id].present?
    @projects = projects
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...

  get "search", to: "search#search"

  ...
end
```

**View**

```
<h1>Search</h1>
<%= form_tag(search_path, method: :get) do %>
  <%= label_tag :name %>
  <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>

  <%= label_tag :category_id %>
  <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(Category.all.collect {|o| [ o.name, o.id ] }, params[:category_id]), { prompt: 'Select Category'}) %>

  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>

<h2><%= pluralize(@projects.count, "Result") %></h2>
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <h3><%= project.name %></h3>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Does the `categories` table have a `name` field?

Comment: @Phlip Indeed it does.

Comment: According to official [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association), you should define your relationship in plural:   has_and_belongs_to_many :projects

Comment: @Rcordoval yes, my apologies. Transcription mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you join two tables and both tables have a `name` column then you have to tell the database which `name` column you want to match.

```
  def search
    @projects = Project.all
    @projects = @projects.where('projects.name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:name]}%") if params[:name].present?
    @projects = @projects.joins(:categories).where(categories: { id: params[:category_id] }) if params[:category_id].present?
  end
```

Note the `projects.name` in the `LIKE` query.

Comment: You can also use `Project.arel_table[:name].matches("%#{params[:name]}%")`