# ActiveRecord Unambiguous Query with Joining table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to combine two common active record queries.

- I need to perform a where clause on a date field
- I need to join 2 tables

Since I am joining them I need to specify the table of the column, a column both tables have ,`created_at`.

I basically need to combine these 2 answers:

[ActiveRecord joins throwing Column in where clause is ambiguous error - Rails 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50111362/activerecord-joins-throwing-column-in-where-clause-is-ambiguous-error-rails-5)

```rb
    @projects = @projects.joins(:categories).where(categories: { id: params[:category_id] }) if params[:category_id].present?
```

[Active Record - Find records which were created_at before today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978018/active-record-find-records-which-were-created-at-before-today)

```rb
MyModel.where("created_at < ?", 2.days.ago)
```

What I have right now is this:

```rb
Train.joins(:schedule).where('created_at >= ?', DateTime.now - 7.days)
```

Which returns:

```
Mysql2::Error: Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous: SELECT
```

Comment: Which table are you trying to use the WHERE clause on? Or both?

Comment: I am attempting to use it on Train

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ambiguous because both tables have `created_at` and it doesn't know which one to look at.

In order to specify a condition on joined tables with the same column name, you can do something like...

```
Train.joins(:schedule).where(trains: { created_at: DateTime.now - 7.days })
```

Or...

```
time_range = DateTime.now - 7.days
Train.joins(:schedule).where('trains.created_at' => time_range)
```

You could also use scopes to accomplish the same thing in, perhaps, a cleaner way. It may be better to implement the WHERE clause on `Train` before joining.

[reference](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables)